# Syncronization for deleted rows is better storing or compare?

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, synchronization, database-performance

I have a Android Aplication that Syncronize with a WebApp in php on the web. But i know the solution for my problem, but i want to knowthe best aproach.

My Android aplication is a offline app that have a button like "Sync" when the user press he goes to my database from my webapp and sync there.

But if the user delete a data on the webapp the only way to Android to know the data that has been deleted to delete in the SQLITE is two ways i think.

1 - First compare the two databases on a loop row per row to know the data that has been deleted. The problem about this is performance.

2 - The second i think is create a table called SyncHistory to put there all the data that the user in the webapp erased and when the user click on sync button from the Android App he already know the data and delete it.

Do you guys know another solution?

Comment: never delete the data, just provide your data with 'deleted' flag. Or you can go to your second approach

Comment: hum ok, but why not delete? I will store so much data desnecessary right?

Comment: what if your client accidentally delete the data and want it back? data should never to be deleted, but they have expire date, like one month or so

Answer (score 0):

When user deletes record from webapp or any other application and when offline device tries to sync, Web service should pass delete flag along with record id in sync payload.

When app receives delete flag, It will delete record of that id which is given by server.